# Dialogflow create context delay

Tags: c#, class, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

When I try and create a context in Dialogflow using the client library in an ASP.NET Core application hosted on Google Compute Engine, I am getting delays of around 5 seconds. This is only the case for the first few requests. After a few requests, the delay frops down to well under a second. My code is:

```
public class Clients
{
    public static ContextsClient contextsClient = ContextsClient.Create();
    ...
}

...

//From here
SessionName sessionName = new SessionName(projectId, sessionId);
Context exampleContext = new Context();
exampleCoontext.LifespanCount = 1;
exampleContext.Name = sessionName + "/contexts/examplecontext";
Context response = Clients.contextsClient.CreateContext(sessionName, exampleContext);
//To here, is where I experience the delay
```

I initially thought it was delay as a result of the actual `contextsClient` being created, however, the client should already be created in the `Clients` class. Even if I sleep the thread for several seconds before I create the context (essentially allowing for the `contextsClient` to be created), I get the delay for the first few requests?

What could be causing this? Or am I wrong in thinking that the `contextsClient` is being created in the `Clients` class?

Comment: If you've timed specifically the `CreateContext` call, then it's almost certainly just that the RPC takes that long - there's nothing the client library can do at that point. If you *haven't* isolated it to `CreateContext`, that's the next thing to do. Separate out obtaining the client from calling `CreateContext` by using two different statements: `ContextsClient client = Clients.contextsClient; Context response = client.CreateContext(...);`. Add appropriate timing code, and then put the results in your question.

Comment: i also experience this same delay in NodeJS

Comment: @pariola What have you done to solve this? My answer below explains what I am currently doing.

Comment: Formerly i was using this on Google Cloud Functions, later today i implemented the same setup on a Digital Ocean droplet and the time delay reduced to half a second. @HarryStuart

Comment: Interesting, I actually quite like my solution as it solves the delay problem, but also keeps my site refreshed every 30 min which allows me to run diagnostic tests that often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jon said, it seems as if the delay in the RPC is simply how long it actually takes. My application is running on windows server 2016 and what I have done, is essentially created a powershell script that makes an HTTP request to my application every 45 minutes as a windows scheduled task. This http request triggers my application to literally make a create context request, and effectively, refreshing the client by doing so every interval and therefore, my users don’t experience the delay.